# ServiceStack JsonSerializer not serializing public members

Tags: c#, json, serialization, servicestack, jsonserializer

I'm trying to use ServiceStack.Redis and i notice that when i store an object with public members and try to get it later on i get null.

I checked and found that ServiceStack.Redis is using ServiceStack.JsonSerializer so I've tried to create a test case and i notice that ServiceStack.JsonSerializer not serializing public members:

```
        public class ClassA
        {
            public string Id;

            public string Id2 { get; set; }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassA t = new ClassA();
            t.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");
            t.Id2 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");

            string a = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString<ClassA>(t);

            ClassA t2 = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<ClassA>(a);

            Console.WriteLine("id " + t2.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("id2 " + t2.Id2);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

As you can see (if you test that code) that Id (public member) is null and Id2 (public property) is the same string that we entered.

So what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Default JsonSerializer serialize only properties. Check it http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb410770.aspx to get info about attributes which can be used to affect the serialization process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tell the JsonSerializer to include public fields.

```
ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.IncludePublicFields = true;
```